# How do I write a script in Scala that converts the current time to the number of seconds since midnight?

Tags: scala

I'm new to all of this; I'm currently taking CSC 101 and learning how to use Scala. This is our first assignment, and I don't know where to start.  I was wondering if you could explain what each variable means and what it stands for?
I've been seeing the code below a lot, and I don't know what the percent signs mean or what they do.

```
val s = System.currentTimeMillis / 1000
val m = (s/60) % 60
val h = (s/60/60) % 24
```

Comment: It's called the modulo operator. Have a look here: wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: s = seconds, m = minutes, h = hours. “millis” are milliseconds (= 1/1000 second).

Comment: try it in REPL or Eclipse Worksheet and experiment with % - the easiest way to visualize and learn

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not very straightforward. Here is some code for you:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Calendar

val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
val now = cal.getTime()

val thisDay = formatter.format(now)
val midnight = formatter.parse(thisDay)

// milliseconds since midnight
val msSinceMidnight = now.getTime - midnight.getTime
val secSinceMidnight = msSinceMidnight / 1000
println(secSinceMidnight)
```

You have to use Java APIs as shown above, or you could choose to use JodaTime library: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/.